# What is the hierarchy of aviation regulatory bodies?

Tags: regulations, international

What does the hierarchy of the aviation bodies look like?

Does it look like this:

International: ICAO

Continental: EASA,ECAC,...?

National:?

Comment: ICAO is organisation that draw "recommendations" for its members to use. Each country has control of its own airspace and surrounding area. EASA is a group of european countries so it is equal to national.

Comment: @vasin1987 I hope you don't mind that I built an answer around your comment.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling feel free. It is a fact (I hope!). I'm too lazy to format it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [vasin1987](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/679/vasin1987) in a comment to the question, each country's regulatory body has control of that country's airspace: These agencies exist in a "mesh" of coequals as opposed to a hierarchy.

The [EASA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Aviation_Safety_Agency) is a EU agency and applies to all of EU, very similar to how the [FAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Aviation_Administration) is a US agency that applies to all of the US.

[ICAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Civil_Aviation_Organization), in turn, deals primarily with situations where air traffic crosses regulatory borders. In its own words, borrowing from the page [About ICAO](http://www.icao.int/about-icao/Pages/default.aspx) on their web site,

> The International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO) is a UN specialized agency [which works] to reach consensus on international civil aviation Standards and Recommended Practices (SARPs) and policies[.]

Like pretty much the rest of the UN, the ICAO is more a forum for cooperation between regulatory bodies than a regulatory body in its own right.

Comment: Hum... ICAO coordinates the signature of treaties ([list](http://www.icao.int/secretariat/legal/Lists/Current%20lists%20of%20parties/AllItems.aspx)). Are you sure [treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty) don't have "force of law"? On the other hand, it's a side point, but EASA is not a ruling agency, each country in EU is sovereign. EASA directives are translated into local laws voted by local parliaments, which are the only elected bodies.

Comment: @mins Treaties have the force of law between the signing countries, and it is up to those signing countries to enact and enforce legislation for its citizens to abide by those treaties. If treaties themselves were law as it applied to citizens, we would get treaties as appendices to our FAR books. The mere act of signing a treaty doesn't enact legislation (laws), that comes later.

Comment: @RonBeyer. It seems this is a bit more complex: "*In the United States, a different principle is established. Our constitution declares a treaty to be the law of the land. It is, consequently, to be regarded in courts of justice as equivalent to an act of the legislature, whenever it operates of itself, without the aid of any legislative provision*" ([source](http://law.justia.com/constitution/us/article-2/18-treaties-as-law-of-the-land.html)).

Comment: @mins Indeed it is, I think the key part of that is "whenever it operates of itself without the aid of any legislative provision...", probably a better question for law.se.

Comment: Mmm, so you could say the FAA and the EASA work on a continental scale? Are there more of these? Like an asian one? And what organizations work on a national scale and is there a layer deeper than that? And is the IATA anywhere to be found?

Comment: @Thepizzaguy *"Mmm, so you could say the FAA and the EASA work on a continental scale?"* No, "continent" is something quite different from "administrative division", "country" or "regulatory region".

Comment: @mins It's worth noting that the US government has a history of ignoring "inconvenient" provisions in our treaties (If one needs evidence of this look no further than our treaties with our indigenous peoples). We respect the provisions of treaties like [the Chicago Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Convention_on_International_Civil_Aviation) facilitated through ICAO because we recognize tangible (economic) benefits from them, but we could also simply not implement provisions of the treaty in our regulatory structure…