# How do aviation regulatory bodies relate to each other?

Tags: safety, regulations, icao, iata

I am trying to make a overview how regulatory bodies in aviation safety interrelate. Maybe something like a  hierarchy. I would start with ICAO and IATA, but where comes then for example FAA, CAA, LBA? Thanks for trying to help me...

Comment: Hello Ayiko, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com. A few related questions have been asked already, you might find the answer there.  For example: [What is the difference between ICAO, JAA, FAA, EASA, and CAA?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1210/19)

Comment: I could not find my answer in the article you provided. I do not need a explanation of those organisations but some kind of hierarchy. Who would be on top of it (ICAO, IATA), ater that for example we move towards European regulations and in the end government and local authorities.

Comment: Also see, [What is the hierarchy of aviation regulatory bodies?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32515/14897) Check all the linked post, and if something is not yet clear, feel free to specify the problem by [revising the post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/55890/edit). The gist of it is, there isn't a hierarchy per se as posed in the question.